# Converting colour in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my `Windows Phone application` I get the colour from xml and then bind it to some element.
I have found that I get the wrong colour in my case.

Here is my code:

```
 var resources = feedsModule.getResources().getColorResource("HeaderColor") ??
     FeedHandler.GetInstance().MainApp.getResources().getColorResource("HeaderColor");
     if (resources != null)
     {
      var colourText = Color.FromArgb(255,Convert.ToByte(resources.getValue().Substring(1, 2), 16),
                       Convert.ToByte(resources.getValue().Substring(3, 2), 16),
                      Convert.ToByte(resources.getValue().Substring(5, 2), 16));
```

So after converting the colour, I get the wrong result. In xml I have this one:

```
 <Color name="HeaderColor">#FFc50000</Color>
```

and it converts into `#FFFFC500`

Comment: I think you should either use Color.FromRgb instead of Color.FromArgb, or you should use Color.FromArgb with alpha to 0 instead of 255.

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't have Color.FromRgb, only Color.FromArgb. If I use alpha to 0 instead of 255 I get white colour

Comment: Because if you use 0 instead of 255, the color is actually transparent so you should leave 255. Do you get RED instead of BLUE in this case?

Comment: ok, but how can I get the right one?

Comment: I have #0000FF, after conveting I get #FF0000FF, the question is, how can I get correct result?

Comment: It is the correct result. #0000FF is in #rrggbb format, and #FF000FF is in #aarrggbb format, but they are the same if alpha is 255. Have you tried binding or rendering the colors to see if they're the same?

Comment: I have Update my question with colours that is not converting ok

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use some 3rd-party converter.

[Here is one of them](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2011/03/16/silverlight-convert-hex-string-to-color/).

Then you can use it so:

```
Color color = (Color)(new HexColor(resources.GetValue());
```

Also you can use the method from [this link](http://silverlemma.blogspot.com/2009/03/c-converting-from-hex-string-to-color.html), it works as well.

```
public Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
{
    //remove the # at the front
    hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

    byte a = 255;
    byte r = 255;
    byte g = 255;
    byte b = 255;

    int start = 0;

    //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
    if (hex.Length == 8)
    {
        a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        start = 2;
    }

    //convert RGB characters to bytes
    r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```