# Pass color between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to pass color from ColorPicker (Code4fun controll) to another page.

I pass parameter like this:

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GeneratePage.xaml?&foreground=" + qrCodeColorPicker.Color, UriKind.Relative));
```

And I have problem with get value on the Generator Page.

```
var colorCode = NavigationContext.QueryString["foreground"];
Foreground = colorCode;
```

Error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'

Do you know how can I get value on the second page ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11739523/969613) may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess,

```
var colorCode = "#FFDFD991";
```

`Foreground = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorCode);`

Comment: colorCode is a variable which I want to store color. Where can I find ColorConverter ?

Comment: I meant what specific value does colorCode contain? My answer is final.

Comment: It contain ARGB values. I mean for example System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255) // Blue

Answer (score 0):

you can make a converter like this ...

```
private Color ConvertHexStringToColour(string hexString)
{
  byte a = 0;
  byte r = 0;
  byte g = 0;
  byte b = 0;
  if (hexString.StartsWith("#"))
  {
    hexString = hexString.Substring(1, 8);
  }
  a = Convert.ToByte(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(0, 2), 
      System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
  r = Convert.ToByte(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(2, 2), 
      System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
  g = Convert.ToByte(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(4, 2), 
      System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
  b = Convert.ToByte(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
  return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

then use it like

```
var colorCode =  ConvertHexStringToColour(NavigationContext.QueryString["foreground"]);
```

Comment: It's not working. Error An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @Frappeer What does your color code look like? This converter has been written for a ARGB code (#12345678). Maybe you have a RGB code (#123456)

Comment: He is passing 'qrCodeColorPicker.Color'. The default ToString() will return something like "Red". So he also should convert it to hex string I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The query is returning a `string` and you can't just asign in to a `color variable`.
So, there are two options for you

1. Use [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and pass it the int conversion from the
   `substrings` of `string` you just received.
2. Use [`IsolatedStorageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and add it on this page and use
   it on next page.
   Like `Foreground = (Color)isoSettings["passedColor"];`

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working for you, try this method.

Before navigating to the other page,

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Foreground"] = qrCodeColorPicker.Color;
```

In the OnNavigateTo of the next page, get back the color:

```
Color foregroundColor = (Color)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Forground"];
```

Of course, check for null and all.